# How to turn off Apple TV?

Tags: appletv

I have a Apple TV 3rd generation and I know that I can navigate to Settings etc to turn it off. While this works, it's kind of cumbersome. Are there easier ways to turn an Apple TV off?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean sleep. Which effectively is turning it off.

On 3rd Gen.

Hold down the Play/Pause button for 5 seconds.
The Apple TV will go to sleep.

On the 4th Gen.

Hold down the the Home button for a couple of seconds, Looks like a TV.

You will then get a option dialogue to Sleep or cancel.

Comment: On 3rd Gen, holding down the Play/Pause button for 5 seconds will not turn off Apple TV unless you are at the Home screen. I hate that steps are required to power off a device. So annoying...

Comment: Unfortunately it does not say anything about that.. https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204332